# When two polynomials of several variables are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $P(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=Q(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be two polynomials with rational coefficients such that total degree of P and Q are same and $P(m_1,\ldots,m_n)=Q(m_1,\ldots,m_n)$ for all large $(m_1,\ldots,m_n)\in{\mathbb {N}}^n$ where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of all non-negative integers.

Is $P(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=Q(X_1,\ldots,X_n) ?$

Comment: Yes.  The set where two distinct polynomials don't agree is open.  Finite sets are never open unless the 'space' is a vector space over a finite field.

Comment: @aginensky : Can you please explain your last statement.

Comment: @user85835: if you are the owner of this question, please use the [contact us form](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact) with the reason "I need to merge user profiles". The SE team will then be able to help you regain ownership of the question.